# D3 - Chart with positive and negative values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I am trying to build the d3 chart with the positive and negative number values as below [image]

and I found some examples of [this](https://observablehq.com/@d3/diverging-bar-chart) and [this](https://bl.ocks.org/HarryStevens/f1e0de06f1e3f014e9233b80e3514849). I am facing difficulties in customizing it because I have no prior experience in d3 and I think it would need some time for learning. I tried that as well. Created some simple chart examples but could not achieve the above. So I thought of reaching for help. Maybe someone can help with this if they have already done a similar chart or some guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step would be to identify how this chart can be simplified. Removing features until the most basic thing remains. Then, build that and gradually add features until it resembles what you want.

In your case, that'd be a horizontal bar chart. Then, add some negative values and a centred zero-line. Finally, make the height of the bars less so they become nodes, and add the text.

I'll try to add something like this, in these steps, without the layout and everything, but hopefully you'll be able to see my logic.

**The basic vertical bar chart**

```js
// Some fake data
const data = ['SaaS', 'Sales', 'Fruits & Veggies', 'IT'].map((v, i) => ({
  name: v,
  value: 3 * i + 2
}));

const width = 600,
  height = 300
margin = {
  top: 20,
  left: 100,
  right: 40,
  bottom: 40
};

// Process it to find the x and y axis domains
// scaleLinear because it considers numbers
const x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data.map(d => d.value))]) // the possible values
  .range([0, width]); // the available screen space

// scaleBand because it's just categorical data
const y = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map(d => d.name)) // all possible values
  .range([height, 0]) // little weird, y-axis is always backwards, because (0,0) is the top left
  .padding(0.1);

const svg = d3.select('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

const g = svg
  // Append a container element. This will hold the chart
  .append('g')
  // Move it a little to account for the axes and labels
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left} ${margin.right})`);

// Draw the bars
// First, assign the data to the bar objects, this will decide which to remove, update, and add
const bars = g.append('g')
  .selectAll('rect')
  .data(data);

// Good practice: always call remove before adding stuff
bars.exit().remove();

// Add the new bars and assign any attributes that do not depend on the data
// for example, font for texts
bars.enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('fill', 'steelblue')
  // Now merge it with the existing bars
  .merge(bars)
  // From now on we operate on both the old and the new bars
  // Bars are weird, first we position the top left corner of each bar
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', d => y(d.name))
  // Then we determine the width and height
  .attr('width', d => x(d.value))
  .attr('height', y.bandwidth())

// Draw the x and y axes
g.append('g')
  .classed('x-axis', true)
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))

g.append('g')
  .classed('y-axis', true)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Now I'll remove all old comments and explain what I'm doing differently.

**The negative horizontal bar chart**

```js
// Now, the data can also be negative
const data = ['SaaS', 'Sales', 'Fruits & Veggies', 'IT'].map((v, i) => ({
  name: v,
  value: 3 * i - 5
}));

const width = 600,
  height = 300,
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    left: 100,
    right: 40,
    bottom: 40
  };

// Now, we don't use 0 as a minimum, but get it from the data using d3.extent
const x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data.map(d => d.value)))
  .range([0, width]);

const y = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map(d => d.name))
  .range([height, 0])
  .padding(0.1);

const svg = d3.select('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

const g = svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left} ${margin.right})`);

const bars = g.append('g')
  .selectAll('rect')
  .data(data);

bars.exit().remove();

bars.enter()
  .append('rect')
  .merge(bars)
  // All the same until here
  // Now, if a bar is positive it starts at x = 0, and has positive width
  // If a bar is negative it starts at x < 0 and ends at x = 0
  .attr('x', d => d.value > 0 ? x(0) : x(d.value))
  .attr('y', d => y(d.name))
  // If the bar is positive it ends at x = v, but that means it's x(v) - x(0) wide
  // If the bar is negative it ends at x = 0, but that means it's x(0) - x(v) wide
  .attr('width', d => d.value > 0 ? x(d.value) - x(0) : x(0) - x(d.value))
  .attr('height', y.bandwidth())
  // Let's color the bar based on whether the value is positive or negative
  .attr('fill', d => d.value > 0 ? 'darkgreen' : 'darkred')

g.append('g')
  .classed('x-axis', true)
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))

g.append('g')
  .classed('y-axis', true)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

And now, I'll change the bars to the nodes you have in your example code.

**The horizontal chart with nodes**

```js
const data = ['SaaS', 'Sales', 'Fruits & Veggies', 'IT'].map((v, i) => ({
  name: v,
  value: 3 * i - 5
}));

// We want to center each rect around the value it's supposed to have.
// That means that we need to have a node width
const nodeWidth = 60;

const width = 600,
  height = 300,
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    left: 100,
    right: 40,
    bottom: 40
  };

// We also need to make sure there is space for all nodes, even at the edges.
// One way to get this is by just extending the domain a little.
const domain = d3.extent(data.map(d => d.value));
const x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([domain[0] - 1.5, domain[1] + 1.5])
  .range([0, width]);

const y = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map(d => d.name))
  .range([height, 0])
  .padding(0.1);

const svg = d3.select('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

const g = svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left} ${margin.right})`);

const bars = g.append('g')
  .selectAll('rect')
  .data(data);

bars.exit().remove();

// All the same until here
bars.enter()
  .append('rect')
  // width has become a constant
  .attr('width', nodeWidth)
  // Now, transform each node so it centers around the value it's supposed to have
  .attr('transform', `translate(${-nodeWidth / 2} 0)`)
  // Round the corners for aesthetics
  .attr('rx', 15)
  .merge(bars)
  // `x` denotes the placement directly again
  .attr('x', d => x(d.value))
  .attr('y', d => y(d.name))
  .attr('height', y.bandwidth())
  .attr('fill', d => d.value > 0 ? 'darkgreen' : 'darkred');

// Now one more thing, we want to add labels to each node.
// `<rect>` can't have children, we we add them to the plot seperately
// using the same `data` as for the bars
const labels = g.append('g')
  .selectAll('text')
  .data(data);

labels.exit().remove();

labels.enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr('fill', 'white')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle') // center-align the text
  .attr('dy', 5) // place it down a little so it middles nicely in the node.
  .merge(bars)
  // `x` denotes the placement directly
  .attr('x', d => x(d.value))
  // Add half a bar's height to target the center of each node 
  .attr('y', d => y(d.name) + y.bandwidth() / 2)
  // Actually fill in the text
  .text(d => d.value);

g.append('g')
  .classed('x-axis', true)
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))

g.append('g')
  .classed('y-axis', true)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

I hope you can follow this. Let me know if anything about this tutorial is unclear.