# D3 v4 chart with Bi directional chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

[image]

How to create this chart with D3? Any help will help full tried with High charts but not help full much
click event is not working on this drill down event is added but it won't work on click on bars or y-axis labels.

```
const data = [
  { "name": 'IT', "value": 20, "negativeValue": -80 },
  { "name": 'Capital Invest', "value": 30, "negativeValue": -70 },
  { "name": 'Infrastructure', "value": 40, "negativeValue": -60 }
];
```

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        drillUpText: `◁ Back to {series.description}`,
    },
});

Highcharts.chart({
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    renderTo: 'alignmentChart',
    height: 530,
    marginRight: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    events: {
      drilldown(e: any) {
        if (e.seriesOptions.fits) {
          linesPositive = e.seriesOptions.line;
        } else {
          lineNegative = e.seriesOptions.line;
        }
        labels = !!e.seriesOptions && e.seriesOptions.data.map(a => a.name);
      },
      drillup(e: any) {
        if (e.seriesOptions.fits) {
          linesPositive = e.seriesOptions.line;
        } else {
          lineNegative = e.seriesOptions.line;
        }
        labels = !!e.seriesOptions && e.seriesOptions.data.map(a => a.name);
      },
    },
  },
  title: {
    text: '',
  },
  colors: ['#f7a704', '#458dde'],
  // tooltip: this.getTooltip(this),
  xAxis: {
    reversed: false,
    tickPositions: Array.from(Array(this.multi.positive.length).keys()),
    labels: {
      useHTML: true,
      formatter() {
        return `<span title="${labels[this.value]}">${labels[this.value]}</span>`;
      },
      style: {
        color: '#000000',
      },
      step: 1,
    },
    lineWidth: 0,
    tickWidth: 0,
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: null,
    },
    max: 100,
    min: -100,
    plotLines: [{
      color: '#e5e5e5',
      value: 0,
      width: 1,
      zIndex: 20,
    }],
    lineWidth: 1,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    tickWidth: 1,
    // offset: 100,
    labels: {
      y: 30,
      align: 'center',
    },
  },

  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      pointWidth: 12,
    },
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: '#6b6b6b',
        style: {
          fontSize: '12px',
          fontFamily: 'Proxima Nova'
        },
        formatter() {
          return '';
        },
        inside: false,
      },
    },
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Fits Role',
    description: 'Subfunctions',
    data: this.multi.positive,
    type: undefined
  }, {
    name: 'Not Fit Role',
    description: 'Subfunctions',
    data: this.multi.negative,
    type: undefined
  }],
  drilldown: {
    allowPointDrilldown: false,
    activeAxisLabelStyle: {
      fontSize: '12px',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      color: '#007bc7',
      textDecoration: 'none',
    },
    series: this.multi.drilldowns,
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false,
  },
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [D3 - Chart with positive and negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64341815/d3-chart-with-positive-and-negative-values) - up to the second snippet in the answer

Comment: Hi Ruben, That will help but not sure exactly how to plot the bars starting from zero to respective point means 50% or 70% or 100%. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Use `x.domain([-1, 1])`. Add one `g` node per category, with inside it two `rect` nodes. One for bad fit, one for good fit. Because `x.domain` is centred around 0, you can just draw an axis at `transform(${x(0)}, 0)`. If you want more, please post sample data first

Comment: sample data, [{"name": 'IT',"value":20,"negativeVale":-80},{"name": 'Capital Invest',"value":30,"negativeVale":-70},{"name":'Infrastructure',"value":40,"negativeVale":-60}]

Answer (score 0):

I had to make only very few changes compared to [the answer I shared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64343197/5015356). As I said in my comment, I create one `g` node per item, and draw two `rect`s for every one.

Then I update the `rect`s to have the same datum shape (`{ name: string, value: number }`), regardless of whether it's positive or negative. That allows me to do exactly the same things for both types.

```js
// Now, the data can also be negative
const data = [{
  "name": 'IT',
  "value": 20,
  "negativeValue": -80
}, {
  "name": 'Capital Invest',
  "value": 30,
  "negativeValue": -70
}, {
  "name": 'Infrastructure',
  "value": 40,
  "negativeValue": -60
}];

const width = 600,
  height = 300,
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    left: 100,
    right: 40,
    bottom: 40
  };

// Now, we don't use 0 as a minimum, but get it from the data using d3.extent
const x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-100, 100])
  .range([0, width]);

const y = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map(d => d.name))
  .range([height, 0])
  .padding(0.1);

const svg = d3.select('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

const g = svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left} ${margin.right})`);

// One group per data entry, each holding two bars
const barGroups = g
  .selectAll('.barGroup')
  .data(data);

barGroups.exit().remove();

const newBarGroups = barGroups.enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'barGroup');

// Append one bar for the positive value, and one for the negative one
newBarGroups
  .append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'positive')
  .attr('fill', 'darkgreen');

newBarGroups
  .append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'negative')
  .attr('fill', 'darkred');

const positiveBars = newBarGroups
  .merge(barGroups)
  .select('.positive')
  .datum(d => ({
    name: d.name,
    value: d.value
  }));

const negativeBars = newBarGroups
  .merge(barGroups)
  .select('.negative')
  .datum(d => ({
    name: d.name,
    value: d.negativeValue
  }));

newBarGroups.selectAll('rect')
  // If a bar is positive it starts at x = 0, and has positive width
  // If a bar is negative it starts at x < 0 and ends at x = 0
  .attr('x', d => d.value > 0 ? x(0) : x(d.value))
  .attr('y', d => y(d.name))
  // If the bar is positive it ends at x = v, but that means it's x(v) - x(0) wide
  // If the bar is negative it ends at x = 0, but that means it's x(0) - x(v) wide
  .attr('width', d => d.value > 0 ? x(d.value) - x(0) : x(0) - x(d.value))
  .attr('height', y.bandwidth())
// Let's color the bar based on whether the value is positive or negative

g.append('g')
  .classed('x-axis', true)
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))

g.append('g')
  .classed('y-axis', true)
  .attr('transform', `translate(${x(0)}, 0)`)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

---

Alternatively, you can do it without merging the selections like so:

```js
// Now, the data can also be negative
const data = [{
  "name": 'IT',
  "value": 20,
  "negativeValue": -80
}, {
  "name": 'Capital Invest',
  "value": 30,
  "negativeValue": -70
}, {
  "name": 'Infrastructure',
  "value": 40,
  "negativeValue": -60
}];

const width = 600,
  height = 300,
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    left: 100,
    right: 40,
    bottom: 40
  };

// Now, we don't use 0 as a minimum, but get it from the data using d3.extent
const x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-100, 100])
  .range([0, width]);

const y = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map(d => d.name))
  .range([height, 0])
  .padding(0.1);

const svg = d3.select('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

const g = svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left} ${margin.right})`);

// One group per data entry, each holding two bars
const positiveBars = g
  .selectAll('.positive')
  .data(data);
positiveBars.exit().remove();
positiveBars.enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'positive')
  .attr('fill', 'darkgreen')
  .merge(positiveBars)
  .attr('x', x(0))
  .attr('y', d => y(d.name))
  // The bar is positive. It ends at x = v, but that means it's x(v) - x(0) wide
  .attr('width', d => x(d.value) - x(0))
  .attr('height', y.bandwidth());

const negativeBars = g
  .selectAll('.negative')
  .data(data);
negativeBars.exit().remove();
negativeBars.enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'negative')
  .attr('fill', 'darkred')
  .merge(negativeBars)
  .attr('x', d => x(d.negativeValue))
  .attr('y', d => y(d.name))
  // The bar is negative. It ends at x = 0, but that means it's x(0) - x(v) wide
  .attr('width', d => x(0) - x(d.negativeValue))
  .attr('height', y.bandwidth());

g.append('g')
  .classed('x-axis', true)
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))

g.append('g')
  .classed('y-axis', true)
  .attr('transform', `translate(${x(0)}, 0)`)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```